# gc memory overhead exceeded in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

My test execution shows "gc memory overhead exceeded" exception in linux cent os 7. I changed jmeter.bat's heap max size 6g and min size as 512m. I am not used any listeners, preprocessor, http header manager. Used regular expression extractor for 2 samplers and constant timer as common. I run my test in terminal and store result in jtl file. I run it for 250 users, rampup period as 1 and scheduler as 5400 seconds. But still issue persist.. 
System configuration:
Ram 8 GB
CPU octa core 3.12 GHz
Swap memory 16 GB

Comment: are you load testing in gui mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually changed Xmx in jmeter.bat file instead of jmeter.sh file since i used linux for this test. Jmeter.bat is supported in windows os and jmeter.sh is supported for Linux os. So that the above mentioned error occurred. Once I changed it in jmeter.sh file it works perfectly.

Comment: I did same. And yet it shows error. My test was executed from a linux machine and I made changes in jmeter.sh file.
What could be the other things that one could do?

Answer (score 2):

You say that you changed **jmeter.bat**, but the problem is on **Linux**, which doesn't use jmeter.bat. Unless it's a typo, try to change jmeter or jmeter.sh (whichever one you use to invoke JMeter).

Generally I would not recommend more than 2GB for moderate use, and 4GB for heavy use. For instance my settings are:

```
HEAP="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m"
```

and I can run up to 300 concurrent users with a lot of samplers/heavy scripting even in GUI mode. Setting larger heap may cause larger pauses on GC, which can cause the exception you are getting.

After you start JMeter, run the following command to make sure the memory settings are indeed as you expect them to be:

```
ps -ef | grep JMeter
```